# Нормальна ли высокая избыточность в Nosql базах?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Знакомлюсь с mongoDB(mongoose.js), ранее опыта с нереляционными бд не имел, да и с реляционными тоже (немного читал). Складывается ощущение, что в Nosql высокая избыточность для увеличения скорости отдачи информации это частая практика и так делать и нужно. Получается при проектировании схем в контексте веб разработки нужно отталкиваться от того как мы данные хотим представлять пользователю. Например чтобы на одной странице сайта выдать имя + фамилию пользователя, а на другой имя + фамилию и еще 20 параметров нужно будет создать 2 схемы. Верны ли мои рассуждения ?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, в MongoDb нет оператора JOIN, который есть в обычных реляционных БД, поэтому если вам нужны имя+фамилия+20 других параметров, то придется это поместить в один документ, даже если вам в другом месте нужна только имя и фамилия без параметров

Comment: Я имел ввиду хранить в одном документе имя + фамилию , а в другом имя + фамилию + 20 параметров. Вопрос именно в том нормальна ли такая избыточность

Comment: Я думаю, что одного документа будет достаточно, потому что в MongoDb можно выбрать, что именно ты хочешь получить из документа. Поэтому просто пишешь запрос, который выбирает имя+фамилию и получаешь только эти данные

Comment: В том и дело, что в том месте, где нужно вытащить только имя и фамилию, будет вытаскиваться только имя и фамилия, несмотря на то, что в документе есть еще 1000 других полей

Comment: Смотри, при выполнении db.inventory.find( { type: 'food' }, { item: 1, qty: 1 } ) будет вытащено 3 поля: item, qty и специальный _id. И нам неважно, что там еще 1000 других параметров

Comment: Всмысле не важно ? Mongo осуществляет поиск из 1000 параметров и находит 2. А это вычисления, которых могло бы не быть.

Comment: Он осуществляет поиск по 2м параметрам, а не по 1000

Answer (score 2):

Я вам скажу так - высокая избыточность в mongodb это данность. Если вы захотите нормализовать данные, значит вы неправильно выбрали БД для своего проекта. Можно конечно делать join данных на уровне приложения, но будут появляться тормоза. Ко всему прочему за консистентностью нормализованных данных нужно будет следить самостоятельно, что не очень просто.